# Rails polymorphic many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying setup a generic sort of web of related objects.  Let say I have 4 models.

- Book
- Movie
- Tag
- Category

I would like to able to do:

```
book = Book.find(1)
book.relations << Tag.find(2)
book.relations << Category.find(3)
book.relations #=> [Tag#2, Category#3]

movie = Movie.find(4)
movie.relations << book
movie.relations << Tag.find(5)
movie.relations #=> [Book#1, Tag#5]
```

Basically I want to be able to take any 2 objects of any model class (or model class that I allow) and declare that they are related.

Obviously I don't want to create a huge mess of join tables.  This seems like it's not quite a has many through association, and not quite a polymorphic association.

Is this something that Rails can support via it's association declarations or should I be rolling my own logic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come up with a bit of solution.  I'm not sure it's the best however.  It seems you cannot have a polymorphic has_many through.

So, I fake it a bit.  But it means giving up the association proxy magic that I love so much, and that makes me sad.  In a basic state, here is how it works.

```
book = Book.find(1)
book.add_related(Tag.find(2))
book.add_related(Category.find(3))
book.related        #=> [Tag#2, Category#3]
book.related(:tags) #=> [Tag#2]
```

I wrapped it up in a reusable module, that can be added to any model class with a single `has_relations` class method.

http://gist.github.com/123966

I really hope I don;t have to completely re-implement the association proxy to work with this though.

Answer (score 7):

Support for polymorphism has improved dramatically since the early days. You should be able to achieve this in Rails 2.3 by using a single join table for all your models -- a Relation model.

```
class Relation
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :child_item, :polymorphic => true
end

class Book
  has_many :pwned_relations, :as => :owner, :class_name => 'Relation'
  has_many :pwning_relations, :as => :child_item, :class_name => 'Relation'

  # and so on for each type of relation
  has_many :pwned_movies, :through => :pwned_relations, 
           :source => :child_item, :source_type => 'Movie'
  has_many :pwning_movies, :through => :pwning_relations, 
           :source => :owner, :source_type => 'Movie'
end
```

A drawback of this kind of data structure is that you are forced to create two different roles for what may be an equal pairing.  If I want to see all the related movies for my Book, I have to add the sets together:

```
( pwned_movies + pwning_movies ).uniq
```

A common example of this problem is the "friend" relationship in social networking apps.
One solution used by Insoshi, among others, is to register an `after_create` callback on the join model ( `Relation`, in this case ), which creates the inverse relationship.  An `after_destroy` callback would be similarly necessary, but in this way at the cost of some additional DB storage you can be confident that you will get all your related movies in a single DB query.

```
class Relation
  after_create do 
    unless Relation.first :conditions => 
      [ 'owner_id = ? and owner_type = ? and child_item_id = ? and child_item_type = ?',       child_item_id, child_item_type, owner_id, owner_type ]
      Relation.create :owner => child_item, :child_item => owner
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do it exactly as you described is the join tables. It's not so bad though, just 6, and you can pretty much set-and-forget them.

Comment: This was just a example.  My actual data model has none of these exact things, but more of everything.  In the end we are looking at a dozen join tables or more if I go this route.

Comment: Yikes... gotcha. I'll give it some more thought.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how closesly related your movies/books db tables are

what if you declared

```
class Items < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  has_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :related_items,
       :class => "Items",
       :join_table => :related_items,
       :foreign_key => "item_id",
       :associated_foreign_key => "related_item_id"
end

class Books < Items
class Movies < Items
```

make sure you put type in your items table