# How to complete this Rails 3 double-sided polymorphic has_many :through relationship (without has_many_polymorphs or other plugins)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, has-many-through

I know this topic has been approached several times before in various ways, but I haven't been able to synthesize the other questions to meet this particular use case for Rails 3:

I am trying to construct a data model in which there are Attachments and Attachables. Any Attachment can be connected with an Attachable, and vice-versa. I would like this to ultimately be used as a combination acts_as plugin (acts_as_attachable and acts_as_attachment).

My current schema uses an Attacher model with two polymorphic belongs_to relationships to attempt to accomplish this.

The specific case outlined here involves an Attachable model (Good) and two Attachment models (Image and Movie).

Here is what I have so far:

**attacher.rb**

```
class Attacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :attachment, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

**good.rb**

```
class Good < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attachment_relations, :as => :attachable, :class_name => 'Attacher'
    has_many :attached_images, :through => :attachment_relations, :source => :attachment, :source_type  => 'Image'
    has_many :attached_movies, :through => :attachment_relations, :source => :attachment, :source_type  => 'Movie'
end
```

**image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attachable_relations, :as => :attachment, :class_name => 'Attacher'
end
```

**movie.rb**

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attachable_relations, :as => :attachment, :class_name => 'Attacher'
end
```

This works insofar as I can do the following:

```
@g = Good.create!
@i = Image.create!
@m = Movie.create!

@g.attached_images << @i
@g.attached_images       # [#<Image id: 1 ... >]

@g.attached_movies << @m
@g.attached_movies       # [#<Movie id: 1 ... >]

@g.attachment_relations  # [#<Attacher id: 1, attachable_id: 1, attachable_type: "Good", attachment_id: 1, attachment_type: "Image" ...>, #<Attacher id: 2, attachable_id: 1, attachable_type: "Good", attachment_id: 1, attachment_type: "Movie" ...>]
```

**The thrust of my question is: can I use associations to construct the following method/return so I can still do things like `@g.attachments.where( ... )`:**

```
@g.attachments           # [#<Image id: 1 ... >, #<Movie id: 1 ... >]
```

I have tried a bunch of things like this:

**good.rb**

```
class Good < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attachment_relations, :as => :attachable, :class_name => 'Attacher'
    has_many :attachments, :through => :attachment_relations
end
```

But they tend to throw me this:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicError: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Good#attachments' on the polymorphic object 'Attachment#attachment'
```

I think I basically need something that could act like `source_type => :any` ...

*Also, this is my first question on StackOverflow, so please let me know if there is anything I can do to improve my question. Thanks in advance! :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have come to the conclusion that there isn't an easy or standard way to do this. The clearest basic solution I have found is from Squeegy's answer to this question: [Rails polymorphic many to many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953521/rails-polymorphic-many-to-many-association), where he references his gist to a reasonably simple [has_relations module](https://gist.github.com/123966).

I think this basically answers my question and serves a good jumping-off point for creating a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

sadly this is really not possible with rails, you can try your luck with this extension: 
https://github.com/kronn/has_many_polymorphs/tree/

You should be ready to go just by adding this line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'kronn-has_many_polymorphs'
```

and running this command inside your rails application folder:

```
bundle
```

Comment: Thanks @Schmurfy. You seem to be correct in that this is not possible without hacking together some new code. I would accept your answer except for that the question specifically asks for a solution that doesn't use has_many_polymorphs, so I think the follow-up answer I provided is more appropriate to people who might stumble across this question in the future.